# how to match the font of an existing view

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, is there a way to make the fonts in a view match those of an existing view in SwiftUI? I don't like the default selections of swiftUI in a certain context, and I'd like some control over the situation.

Here's some code to illustrate:

```swift
struct FontMatchView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Text("Some Controls Here")
            } header: {
                HStack {
                    Text("Header")
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Option") {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives this result:

[image: Mismatched Fonts in Section header]

In the Section Header, I'd like the font in the button on the right (with label "OPTION") to match the label to its left ("HEADER"). I'm guessing this will be hard because the font is not known at the time of view definition. But the choices SwiftUI has made here are "clearly wrong" :-), and I need to fix this.

Is there a way we solve this (other than overriding both fonts)? Ideally, I could say "use a font that is 0.8 x the height of whatever font will be used in view X". But I'd settle for "use the same font as will be used in view X".

Answer (score 0):

You can remove "buttonizing" (which includes adjusting the font) by applying `.buttonStyle(.plain)`. This will make it match the other Text in the current context. If you then want to re-accent it, you may:

```
Button("Option") {}
    .buttonStyle(.plain)
    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
```

That said (and somewhat unrelated), making the button as small as the HEADER text may make it uncomfortably small as a hit area. It may be better to make HEADER larger rather than OPTION smaller.